# Simple relational problem

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship

I'm using entity framework with 3.5 sp1, and I've come across a strange problem. I have a 1 to many relationship and I cant seem to add a value for it.

I have a table "Bookings" and FK in table "Users" (nullable) and FK in table "BookingObjects"

so:

Users 0..1 <-> * Bookings  * <-> 1  BookingObjects

Table: Users
Entity: User
Setname: Users

Table: Bookings
Entity: Booking
Setname: Bookings

Table: BookingObjects
Entity: BookingObject
Setname: BookingObjects

I have in my code:

```
b.UsersReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("BookingsystemEntities.Users", "UserID", 2);
b.BookingObjectsReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("BookingsystemEntities.Bookings", "BookingObjectID", 2);
b.BookingCreated = DateTime.Now;
```

(both values = 2 exists)

For some reason it gives error when I try to add value for BookingObjectsReference.EntityKey that says:

"You can not define the relationship because EntitySet name BookingsystemEntities.Bookings is not valid for her role in the association BookingObjects volume name BookingsystemEntities.FK_Bookings_BookingObjects."   (I have swedish errors so I'm not sure google translated correctly)

Not sure but shouldnt it be BookingsystemEntities.BookingObjects.FK_Bookings_BookingObjects? might be wrong there?

I have several 1 to many relations that works and I cant seem to find what is different with the FK_Bookings_BookingObjects one....

Do anyone have any ideas might be wrong here? I'm running out of ideas, it all looks right

/M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolved

Should be new System.Data.EntityKey("BookingsystemEntities.BookingObjects"